# Act as Timestampable in symfony not working?

Tags: php, symfony1

I have created a model with an actAs: Timestampable configuration. It creates two fields for me: Created at and updated at. But they appear on my form, and they are required fields. Shouldn't they be auto-filled with the current time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the normal behavior, you have to unset them in the `configure()` or `setup()` method of your form. This is a special case the generator does not take into account and maybe it should.

Comment: Symfony get's me sadder every day.

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't appear in your form, but you can always declare what model fields the form class should use by putting this inside your form class...

```
$this->useFields(array('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'));
```

... and leaving out the created_at and updated_at fields.

Comment: Well, they appear, and i'm even using the Jobeet tutorial as source. http://www.symfony-project.org/images/jobeet/1_4/04/job_layout_assets.png